# I have a problem with TextInput. I can't access its contents

Tags: python, variables, get, kivy, textinput

I want to retrieve the text enter the text Input into a variable in the python file. I tried many solution that seen on the net but none worked.

in the Python file:

```
# from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class MainWidget(Widget):  
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def get_text():    
        text = self.root.text_id.text 
        print(text)

    def test(self):
        print("it work")
    
class Counter_app(BoxLayout):
    count_var = 0
    text = StringProperty("0")

    def count_click(self):
        self.count_var += 1 
        self.text = str(self.count_var)

class  appliApp(App):
    def  build(self):
        return MainWidget()

appliApp().run()
```

//in the Kv FILE

MainWidget:

```
<Counter_app>:
    Button:
        background_color: "blue"
        text: "count"
        on_press: root.count_click()
               
    Label:
        text: root.text
        color: "green"
        font_size: "50"
        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
                source: 'images/img2.jpg'

<font@BoxLayout>: 
    Image:
        source: "images/img2.jpg"
        size: 500,500
    Label:
        background_image: "images/img6"
        background_color: "green"
       
<MainWidget>:
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'img3.png'

    Button:
        pos: 300, 100 
        text: "get text"
        on_press: root.get_text()

    TextInput:
        id: 'text_id'
        hint_text: "Enter your name"
```

Comment: Please translate your title to English.

Comment: How can do that

Comment: And also thank you for clearing my questions

Comment: Use the "Edit" link above the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Several problems with your code:

1. Don't use strings for `ids`. You can use strings for `ids`, but it complicates their use.
2. Your `get_text()` method is missing it's `self` parameter. It should be `def get_text(self):`
3. In your `get_text()` method, you are using `self.root.text_id.text`, but the `MainWidget` has no `root` attribute. You should use `self.ids.text_id.text`.

So, applying the above to your code, the `kv` for your `TextInput` becomes:

```
TextInput:
    id: text_id
    hint_text: "Enter your name"
```

And your `get_text()` method becomes:

```
def get_text(self):
    text = self.ids.text_id.text
    print(text)
```

This should do what you want.